# long double returns and ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

i have a c function which returns a `long double`.  i'd like to call this function from python using ctypes, and it mostly works.  setting `so.func.restype = c_longdouble` does the trick -- except that python's float type is a `c_double` so if the returned value is larger than a double, but well within the bounds of a long double, python still gets inf as the return value.  i'm on a 64 bit processor and `sizeof(long double)` is 16.

any ideas on getting around this (e.g. using the decimal class or numpy) without modifying the c code?

Comment: I want to do something similar and posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380004/how-do-i-force-usage-of-long-doubles-with-cython), and now realised that I have essentially the same problem you did. @Autoplectic, may I know what you eventually did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it without modifying the C code.  ctypes seems to have really bad support for `long double`s - you can't manipulate them like numbers at all, all you can do is convert them back and forth between the native `float` Python type.

You can't even use a byte array as the return value instead of a `c_longdouble`, because of the ABI - floating-point values aren't returned in the `%eax` register or on the stack like normal return values, they're passed through the hardware-specific floating-point registers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function return a *subclass* of `c_longdouble`, it will return the ctypes wrapped field object rather than converting to a python `float`. You can then extract the bytes from this (with `memcpy` into a c_char array, for example) or pass the object to another C function for further processing. The `snprintf` function can format it into a string for printing or conversion into a high-precision python numeric type.

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll['libc.so.6']
libm = ctypes.cdll['libm.so.6']

class my_longdouble(ctypes.c_longdouble):
    def __str__(self):
        size = 100
        buf = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
        libc.snprintf(buf, size, '%.35Le', self)
        return buf[:].rstrip('\0')

powl = libm.powl
powl.restype = my_longdouble
powl.argtypes = [ctypes.c_longdouble, ctypes.c_longdouble]

for i in range(1020,1030):
    res = powl(2,i)
    print '2**'+str(i), '=', str(res)
```

Output:

```
2**1020 = 1.12355820928894744233081574424314046e+307
2**1021 = 2.24711641857789488466163148848628092e+307
2**1022 = 4.49423283715578976932326297697256183e+307
2**1023 = 8.98846567431157953864652595394512367e+307
2**1024 = 1.79769313486231590772930519078902473e+308
2**1025 = 3.59538626972463181545861038157804947e+308
2**1026 = 7.19077253944926363091722076315609893e+308
2**1027 = 1.43815450788985272618344415263121979e+309
2**1028 = 2.87630901577970545236688830526243957e+309
2**1029 = 5.75261803155941090473377661052487915e+309
```

(Note that my estimate of 35 digits of precision turned out to be excessively optimistic for `long double` calculations on Intel processors, which only have 64 bits of mantissa. You should use `%a` rather than `%e`/`f`/`g` if you intend to convert to a format that is not based on decimal representation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need high-precision floating point, have a look at GMPY.

[GMPY](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) is a C-coded Python extension module that wraps the GMP library to provide to Python code fast multiprecision arithmetic (integer, rational, and float), random number generation, advanced number-theoretical functions, and more.

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/#FUNCCLASSES) contains high-level floating-point arithmetic functions (`mpf`). This is the GMP function category to use if the C type `double' doesn't give enough precision for an application. There are about 65 functions in this category.