# How do I force usage of long doubles with Cython?

Tags: c, gcc, cython, long-double

I apologize in advance for my poor knowledge of C: I use Python to code and have written a few modules with Cython using the standard C functions to effect a great increase in speed. However, I need a range higher  than `1e308`  (yes, you read it right), which is what I currently get by using the type `double complex` and the functions `cexp` and `cabs`.

I tried to use the functions `cexpl` and `cabsl`, and declared my variables to be of type `long double complex`, but I still encounter overflows after `1e308`. This probably means that my compiler converts long doubles to doubles, is that right? But according to Wikipedia,

> With the GNU C Compiler, long double is 80-bit extended precision on x86 processors regardless of the physical storage used for the type (which can be either 96 or 128 bits)..[4]

I am using a 64-bit system with arch Linux (and Python 2.7.8 if it matters).

How do I write a Cython module that forces the use of long doubles? I need such big numbers for some scientific computation I am doing.

**Edit:**
Compiling with the flag -m128bit-long-double gives the same result. As indicated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html),

> In the x86-64 compiler, -m128bit-long-double is the default choice as its ABI specifies that long double is to be aligned on 16 byte boundary.

So this seems to make no difference.

I also ran this following program to check the range on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Storage size for float : %d \n", sizeof(float));
   printf("Minimum float positive value: %E\n", FLT_MIN );
   printf("Maximum float positive value: %E\n", FLT_MAX );
   printf("Precision value: %d\n", FLT_DIG );

   printf("Storage size for double : %d \n", sizeof(double));
   printf("Minimum double positive value: %E\n", DBL_MIN );
   printf("Maximum double positive value: %E\n", DBL_MAX );
   printf("Precision value: %d\n", DBL_DIG );

   printf("Storage size for long double : %d \n", sizeof(long double));
   printf("Minimum long double positive value: %Le\n", LDBL_MIN );
   printf("Maximum long double positive value: %Le\n", LDBL_MAX );
   printf("Precision value: %d\n", LDBL_DIG );

   return 0;
}
```

and got the following output:

```
Storage size for float : 4 
Minimum float positive value: 1.175494E-38
Maximum float positive value: 3.402823E+38
Precision value: 6
Storage size for double : 8 
Minimum double positive value: 2.225074E-308
Maximum double positive value: 1.797693E+308
Precision value: 15
Storage size for long double : 16 
Minimum long double positive value: 3.362103e-4932
Maximum long double positive value: 1.189731e+4932
Precision value: 18
```

So I guess the problem lies in my code, is that right? Are there any explicit identifiers I need to add other than declaring variables to ensure that my program actually uses long doubles?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I'm not sure if it's right... but if you can add compiler flags, try either `-m96bit-long-double` or `-m128bit-long-double` and see what happens. [This question might be useful as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516476/long-double-gcc-specific-and-float128) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! I updated the question. How do I check whether my compiler (gcc) is really using 80 or 96 bit long doubles with a range of around `1e4392` apart from getting the overflow?

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423404/long-double-returns-and-ctypes?lq=1) that shows that my C module was returning long doubles, but was being interpreted by Python as `inf` because it exceeded the size of a `double`. As it stands, my question is not really the right question to ask because it stood on a faulty premise. How can I vote to close it? Or should I let this question remain for someone else who might think the same?

Comment: Good on ya for putting in the work and figuring out the problem. If I were you, I would write up my solution, post it as an answer, and accept it for future reference. This practice is [actively supported](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was seen in the edit to the question, my system and compiler was behaving as expected by printing the correct range for `long double`, the relevant variable here being `LDBL_MAX = 1.189731e+4932`

Also, the module written with Cython was correctly giving an output of type `long double`.
However, since this type is not natively supported in Python (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423404/long-double-returns-and-ctypes?lq=1) question), the value that was returned was greater than the maximum size of `double` ,`1.797693E+308` on my system and hence being equated to `+inf + 0j`. So this was not related to gcc at all, but to Python interpreting long doubles in an incorrect way.

I can hopefully get around this by working with another C module that can accept long double input types and process it further, the expected results from this sub-part is not expected to be outside the range of a `double` (or for that matter, even a `float`).

Another option might be to use libraries with Python that can support high precision and high range numbers, possibly [GMPY](http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/).