# Returning a quad precision variable from fortran

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes, gfortran

So i'm trying to return a quad precision (128 bit) value from fortran and manipulate it in python. But the return value i get does not seem to match what i expect.

Fortran code:

```
module testquad

    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(p=30)

    contains

    real(qp) function func_quad()
        real(qp) :: x

        x = 5_qp

        write(*,*) x,sizeof(x)
        write(*,'(B128)') x

        func_quad = x

    end function func_quad

end module testquad
```

Compiled with:

```
gfortran -fpic -shared -fdump-tree-all -o libtestquad.so testQuad.f90
```

Python side I use a c_ubyte*16 array to hold the return value (as ctypes doesn't expose a 128 bit quad type)

```py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libtestquad.so')

f = getattr(lib, '__testquad_MOD_func_quad')

f.argtypes = []
f.restype = ctypes.c_ubyte*16

result = f()

bb=[]
for i in bytearray(result)[::-1]:
    bb.append(bin(i)[2:].rjust(8,'0'))

bb=''.join(bb)
print(bb)
```

Running the code the output from calling the fortran function is:

```
5.00000000000000000000000000000000000                         16
 1000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So we get the 5 and we see the size is 16 (so i am getting a quad number)

It seems gfortran skips printing the first 0/1 for the sign bit. But we can see it has 3 1's and the rest are 0's in the bit pattern.

Following the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) on quad's then we have

```
sign = 0 (gfortran misses this)
exponent = 100000000000001
significand = 0100....
```

Converting that out:

```py
a = 2**(int('100000000000001',base=2)-16383) # 4
b = 1 + 0/2**1 + 1/2**2 + 0/2**3 .... # 1.25
print(a * b)
5
```

So gfortran is, as expected, printing the right bit pattern for the number 5.

However, printing out a bit pattern in python for the result:

```
00000000000000000111111110110001001111101010010111111001001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Which is clearly different.

Have i screwed up printing the bit pattern?

Is there something special in how gfortran returns a __float128 that means I can't just interpret it as 16 bytes?

Is there something special in how ctypes handles returning an array of c_bytes that breaks things?

Something else?

Extras:

using -fdump-tree-all and looking at the .original file we see:

```
func_quad ()
{
  real(kind=16) x;
  real(kind=16) __result_func_quad;

  x = 5.0e+0;
  // snip write statement code
  __result_func_quad = x;
  return __result_func_quad;
}
```

So it seems there is nothing "special" going on, variables are not being assigned to structs/pointers/arrays to handle the quad type.

Comment: Of course, gfortran does not print the sign bit for +5.  From the Fortran 2018 standard: _The output field for the Bw, Ow, and Zw descriptors consists of zero or more leading blanks followed by the internal value in a form identical to the digits of a binary, octal, or hexadecimal constant, respectively, that specifies the same bit sequence but without leading zero bits._  Simply printing the bit pattern for -5 shows a leading `1` for the sign bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i'm running into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/423479/2270574 answer. Which points out you can't use a byte array for a floating point number as its not stored in the normal %eax register.